# PHP ldap_list() Bad search filter

Tags: php, authentication, active-directory, ldap

I'm trying to list my Active Directory users using PHP ldap_list() function. I get the following errors when I execute the php code.

`LDAP bind successful... Warning: ldap_list(): Search: Bad search filter in /var/www/html/ldapn.php on line 29`

Below is my PHP Code:

```
<?php

// using ldap bind
$ldaprdn  = 'draven@myserver.com';     // ldap rdn or dn
$ldappass = 'draven678';  // associated password

// connect to ldap server
$ldapconn = ldap_connect("dc.myserver.com")
    or die("Could not connect to LDAP server.");

if ($ldapconn) {

    // binding to ldap server
    $ldapbind = ldap_bind($ldapconn, $ldaprdn, $ldappass);

    // verify binding
    if ($ldapbind) {
        echo "LDAP bind successful...";
    } else {
        echo "LDAP bind failed...";
    }

    $basedn = "dc=myserver, dc=com";
    $justthese = array("OU_Test");

    $sr = ldap_list($ldapconn, $basedn, "OU_Test=*", $justthese);

}

?>
```

note : OU_Test is an Organizational unit. My requirement is to list all users in that Organizational Unit.

What's wrong with my code? How will I be able to resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

To list all users in the Organizational Unit 'OU_TEST' with `ldap_list()` :

- Use the appropriate $basedn. It should be the distinguished name of 'OU_TEST' since you want to list users that are **INSIDE** OU_TEST. You can get it with ldap_search().
- Use the appropriate filter : to list only users, filter by users.

```
 // 1. Get OU_TEST's dn. Search down the tree using a top/root dn as $basedn :
 $basedn = "dc=myserver, dc=com";

 // Filters usually looks like ([attributeName]=[attributeValue])
 $filter = '(ou=OU_TEST)';

 $sr = ldap_search($ds, $basedn, $filter);
```

... say we put the resulting dn in `$OU_TEST_dn` variable...

```
 // 2. List users. If users are missing, use 'objectClass=organizationalPerson'
 $filter = '(objectClass=Users)';

 // Use the correct basedn
 $basedn = $OU_TEST_dn;

 // This should work
 $sr = ldap_list($ldapconn, $basedn, $filter);
```

Answer (score -1):

the filter here should be in braces:

here is how:

```
$sr = ldap_list($ldapconn, $basedn, "(OU_Test=*)", $justthese);
```

This should work just fine.

### If it doesn't work

follow the example [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-bind.php#98351)

```
<?php
$ldapconfig['host'] = '10.10.10.10';
$ldapconfig['port'] = NULL;
$ldapconfig['basedn'] = 'dc=company,dc=com';

$ds=ldap_connect($ldapconfig['host'], $ldapconfig['port']);

$dn="uid=".$username.",ou=OU_TEST,".$ldapconfig['basedn'];

if ($bind=ldap_bind($ds, $dn, $password)) {
  echo("Login correct");
} else {

  echo("Unable to bind to server.</br>");

  echo("msg:'".ldap_error($ds)."'</br>"); //check if the message isn't: Can't contact LDAP server :)
  //if it say something about a cn or user then you are trying with the wrong $dn pattern i found this by looking at OpenLDAP source code :)
  //we can figure out the right pattern by searching the user tree
  //remember to turn on the anonymous search on the ldap server
  if ($bind=ldap_bind($ds)) {

    $filter = "(OU_TEST=*)";

    if (!($search=@ldap_search($ds, $ldapconfig['basedn'], $filter))) {
      echo("Unable to search ldap server<br>");
      echo("msg:'".ldap_error($ds)."'</br>"); //check the message again
    } else {
      $number_returned = ldap_count_entries($ds,$search);
      $info = ldap_get_entries($ds, $search);
      echo "The number of entries returned is ". $number_returned."<p>";
      for ($i=0; $i<$info["count"]; $i++) {

        var_dump($info[$i]); //look for your user account in this pile of junk and apply the whole pattern where you build $dn to match exactly the ldap tree entry
      }
    }
  } else {
    echo("Unable to bind anonymously<br>");
    echo("msg:".ldap_error($ds)."<br>");
  }
}
?>
```

Let me know if it does not work. We will try and figure it out!

Comment: I put braces and I'm still getting the same error. `Warning: ldap_list(): Search: Bad search filter in /var/www/html/ldapn.php on line 29`. When I execute your example I get following errors `Warning: ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server: Invalid credentials in /var/www/html/ldaps.php on line 13 Unable to bind to server.
msg:'Invalid credentials'
Unable to search ldap server
msg:'Bad search filter'`

Comment: did you check if credentials in the example are correct. You need to use `domainname\username` as uesrname

Comment: Yes the credentials are correct because when I execute the code shown in my question. I'm able to bind to the server, I get the following message `LDAP bind successful...`. But when I execute your sample code I get `Unable to bind to server: Invalid credentials`

Comment: are those credentials allowed to access OU_TEST? Also, check `$dn` if it is correct for your OU